# How to post and get radio group arrays?

Tags: php, mysql, html

How can I get the values of the radio groups in an array format? Here is my sender(game.php) and receiver(result.php)

I wanted to check the radio group elements(yes or no) with the correct answers from database and increase the point if its correct.

game.php:

```
    $conn=  mysql_connect($servername,$username, $password)or die(mysql_error());
    mysql_select_db($database,$conn);

    $sql = "SELECT * from questions";
    $result=mysql_query($sql);
    $num=mysql_numrows($result);

    $i=0;
    echo("<FORM ACTION='./result.php' METHOD=GET>");
    while($i < $num){
        $field = array($i => mysql_result($result,$i,"question"));
        $j = $i + 1;
        echo "<b>[$j]  </b>$field[$i]<br>";
        echo ("<label>
      <input type='radio' name='radioGroup[$i]' value='yes' id='radioGroup_1'>
      Yes</label><label>
      <input type='radio' name='radioGroup[$i]' value='no' id='radioGroup_1'>
      No</label><br>");
    $i++;   
    }

    echo "<input type='submit'>"; 
    echo("</FORM>");
    echo("<br>");
```

result.php:

```
    $conn=  mysql_connect($servername,$username, $password)or die(mysql_error());
    mysql_select_db($database,$conn);

    $sqlcode = "SELECT * FROM questions";
    $cal=mysql_query($sqlcode);
    $num = mysql_numrows($cal);
    $m=0;

    while ($m < $num){
        $user_answer = array($m => $_GET["radioGroup"]);    
        $m++;
    }



    $k = 0;
    $point = 0;
    $sql = "SELECT * from questions";
    $result=mysql_query($sql);
    while($k < $num){
        $answer = array($k => mysql_result($result,$k,"answer"));

        if ($answer[$k] == $user_answer[$k]){
            $point++ ;  
        }

        echo "puan:";
        echo $point;
        $k++;
    }
```

Comment: Isn't the same question [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11485682/radio-group-information-added-to-array) ?

Comment: Just a hint: Avoid echoing HTML to the most.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You don't understand how you receive the form values.

In your code (`result.php`) the `$_GET["radioGroup"]` is an array with all answers.

Try this simple script to understand how it works :

```
<form>
    <input type='radio' name='radioGroup[1]' value='yes' checked="checked" />
    <input type='radio' name='radioGroup[1]' value='no'  />
    <br/>
    <input type='radio' name='radioGroup[2]' value='yes'  />
    <input type='radio' name='radioGroup[2]' value='no'  checked="checked"  />
    <br/>
    <input type='submit' name='submit' value='true' />
</form>

<pre>
<?php

    if( isset($_GET['submit']) )
    {   
        print_r($_GET);
    }
```

And output is this :

```
Array
(
    [radioGroup] => Array
        (
            [1] => yes
            [2] => no
        )

    [submit] => true
)
```

Comment: I still didn't understand how to get the results from game.php?